# Compile with iOS 7 and Xcode 5 and submit to AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode

Can I compile my iOS app for iOS 7 using Xcode 5 and submit to app store? Or is it mandatory that i have to compile my app for iOS 8 and use XCode 6 to submit the app?

Note: I have tested my iOS app on iOS 8 beta release. App supports iOS 8.

I have one more question - If I compile my app for iOS 8 will the app runs on iOS 7?

Comment: I just uploaded an app with Xcode 5.1 with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you still cannot submit using iOS 8 as far as I know.  Though it will change very soon if it hasn't already since there is only 1 week left until the official release.  However, you are not required to.  Apple will continue accepting applications built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and will set a firm date for when it will stop in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit using iOS 8 GM Seed (thru Xcode 6), or using iOS 7 with Xcode 5.
Judging by last year's transition, you'll have at least a month or two left to use Xcode 5.

Comment: I have one more question - If I compile my app for iOS 8 will the app runs on iOS 7?

Comment: That depends on your app's deployment target, and whether you're using specific iOS 8 API's (these function calls will be tagged with `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your reference: https://developer.apple.com/ios7/

As long as this ad is active, we are able to compile iOS7 apps using XCode 5 and submit to AppStore.

Comment: the iOS7 ad is gone. Now can i compile the app for iOS7 and still submit it to app store? Or i should mandatory compile for iOS8 to get my app approved?

Comment: Sorry mate, you have to use xcode6 to compile your apps from now on. You also need to adjust your design for iPhone6 & plus

Comment: can i use iOS 7 to compile my apps? and submit them Apple Store?